# Using Pool to recycle and reuse sprites

Tags: java, android, andengine

I created this generic pool to re-use some sprites that i add to the scene.

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private  ITextureRegion texture1;
private  ITextureRegion texture2;
private ITextureRegion texture3;
private  ITextureRegion texture4;
private  ITextureRegion texture5;

private Scene mScene;
private Context mContext;
private Camera mCamera;
private LinkedList<Sprite>pool1;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public FruitPool(final ITextureRegion watermelonRegion,
        ITextureRegion cherryRegion,ITextureRegion mBallTextureRegion, ITextureRegion grapeTextureRegion, ITextureRegion strawberryTextureRegion,Scene mScene2, Camera camera, LinkedList<Sprite>items) {

    this.texture1 = watermelonRegion;
    this.texture2 =cherryRegion;
    this.texture3 = mBallTextureRegion;
    this.texture4 = grapeTextureRegion;
    this.texture5 = strawberryTextureRegion;
    this.mScene = mScene2;
    this.pool1 = items;

    this.mCamera = camera;

}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {

     Random rand = new Random();
     Random randFruit = new Random();
     Sprite fruit = null;
      float x = rand.nextInt((int) mCamera.getWidth() - texture1.getHeight());
     int textureNumber = randFruit.nextInt(5)+1;

     switch(textureNumber){
     case 1:
          fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture1);
          break;
     case 2:
         fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture2);
         break;
     case 3:
         fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture3);
         break;
     case 4:
         fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture4);
         break;
     case 5:
         fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture5);
         break;

     }










    mScene.attachChild(fruit);


    return fruit;

}
@Override
protected void onHandleObtainItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.reset();
}
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.setVisible(false);
    pItem.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

}


// ===========================================================          
// Methods          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Inner and Anonymous Classes          
// ===========================================================
```

The code runs well but it doesnt seem to be reusing the recycled sprites but allocating new ones Each time..

I retrieve a sprite by calling

```
  face =  fruitsPool.onAllocatePoolItem();
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I tried the method in the answer setting it up like this..

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private  ITextureRegion texture1;
private  ITextureRegion texture2;
private ITextureRegion texture3;
private  ITextureRegion texture4;
private  ITextureRegion texture5;

private Scene mScene;
private Context mContext;
private Camera mCamera;
private LinkedList<Sprite>pool1;

private static Sprite fruitOne = null;
private static Sprite fruitTwo= null;
private static Sprite fruitThree = null;
private static Sprite fruitFour = null;
private static Sprite fruitFive = null;
private  Sprite fruit = null;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public FruitPool(final ITextureRegion watermelonRegion,
        ITextureRegion cherryRegion,ITextureRegion mBallTextureRegion, ITextureRegion grapeTextureRegion, ITextureRegion strawberryTextureRegion,Scene mScene2, Camera camera, LinkedList<Sprite>items) {

    this.texture1 = watermelonRegion;
    this.texture2 =cherryRegion;
    this.texture3 = mBallTextureRegion;
    this.texture4 = grapeTextureRegion;
    this.texture5 = strawberryTextureRegion;
    this.mScene = mScene2;
    this.pool1 = items;

    this.mCamera = camera;

}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {


     Random randFruit = new Random();

     int textureNumber = randFruit.nextInt(5)+1;

     switch(textureNumber){
     case 1:
         if (fruitOne == null) {
              fruitOne = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture1);
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item rremade");
            } else {
              fruit = fruitOne;
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
            }
          break;
     case 2:
         if(fruitTwo == null){
          fruitTwo = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture2);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitTwo;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }

         break;
     case 3:
         if(fruitThree == null){
              fruitThree = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture3);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitThree;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }

         break;
     case 4:
         if(fruitFour == null){
             fruitFour = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture4);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitThree;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");

         }

         break;
     case 5:
         if(fruitFive == null){
              fruitFive = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture5);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitFive;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }

         break;

     }


    return fruit;

}
@Override
protected void onHandleObtainItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.reset();
}
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.setVisible(false);
    pItem.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

}



// ===========================================================          
// Methods          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Inner and Anonymous Classes          
// ===========================================================  
}
```

And i call

```
 Sprite sprite = fruitPool.onAllocatePoolItem();

 then i attach it to the scene(this method i use is called about every second)
```

But each time around i get the error that the entity(sprite) already has a parent and has been attached.

Or other times the sprites just return null.

Is there something im doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Is it always attached to same parent?

Comment: Well ive fixed it now, i was never detaching it from the scene from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your `switch(textureNumber)` statement you are creating a `new Sprite()` every time and returning it to the caller. You should be checking if the Sprite has been created before and returning that instance back to the caller.

**Edit**: (Based on comment)

From what I understand, when you `recycle()` it just hides the sprite, so you want to get a reference back to it.

What you can do is make your sprites static objects as part of your class, then change your switch statement, like so:

```
private static Sprite fruitOne;
private static Sprite fruitTwo;
private static Sprite fruitThree;
. . .

//Other code in here

switch(textureNumber) {
  case 1:
    if (fruitOne == null) {
      fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture1);
    } else {
      fruit = fruitOne;
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (fruitTwo == null) {
      fruit = new Sprite(x, 0, this.texture2);
    } else {
      fruit = fruitTwo;
    }
    break;

   //Rest of code here. . .
```

Basically this code checks if there is already an instance of the Sprite created, and if not - it will create one.

Comment: Could you give me an example of checking if its been created before? I call .recycle(sprite); in my code where the sprite should be removed.

Comment: I have no idea why i could never think of that method! Nice! Wow, sometimes its best to seek a little outside help.

Comment: Happy to help any time, it's what SO is for :)

Comment: The only problem i ran into with this method was if the same item is called to be obtained more than once before the first one goes off the screen i get the Sprite Already has a parent error.

Comment: That's because you're attaching it to the parent within that method too - you'll either need to move that call to another method or remove it and then add the sprite to the parent at the time you call `onAllocatePool()`

Comment: oohhhh...I see, ill try that out.

Answer (score 2):

`new` keyword is used to create a new instance of a class by invoking one of the constructors for that class. It doesnot check whether any instance exists or not.

You need to write logic to check whether any instance of the class already exists. if not create a new instance if exists then use the instance

see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/singletons/

Comment: I cant seem to put together how i can check if an instance has already been created in this situation.